# MVC 4 : Possible to use variable from validation in validation message?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation, asp.net-mvc-4

Many forms in my project have a part number input.  Currently in the controller I often times test the part number to see if the part exists or user has access or if the part is obsolete, then based on the condition I reload the view passing a message through a string parameter then viewbag for display to show why the form submit failed.  I'm trying to clean this up and instead use model property validation.

I have a few working well however one of the validations I want to test is if the part is obsolete and has a suggested alternate part number to use.  Based on the property value (part number) I have a service layer method that will return a bool of if the part is obsolete and another one that will return the suggested use part number.  If possible I'd like to trigger the validation on the bool check, then pass that alternate part number into the validation message that gets generated.

Here is the validation code in it's current form:

```
public class PartAlternateValidation : ValidationAttribute
{
    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        if (value == null)
        {
            return false;
        }

        GP10Service gp10svc = new GP10Service();

        //string altPart = gp10svc.GetPartAlternate(value.ToString());

        return gp10svc.CheckPartAlternate(value.ToString());
    }
}
```

Did quite a bit of searching around but couldn't find anything that specifically discussed this.  Thinking maybe I could have an out string parameter with the bool in IsValid, but not sure how to then pass that to the message (or call FormatErrorMessage method from the IsValid method?).  Thinking maybe there is a way using ModelState.AddModelError, however I believe the key on these is tied to the property, correct?  So I'm fuzzy on how I could detect when the property fails a particular validation and use the property value as a variable in generating the message that way.

Probably something simple, has been a good excuse to do more research and I will continue reading but any suggestions or tips would be welcome.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see below tip helps..

**Model:**

```
namespace Mvc4Test.Models
{
    public class Part
    {
        [AlternateValidation(Suggetion = "Please Use 123 (This is a Suggestion)")]
        public string PartNumber { get; set; }
    }

    public class AlternateValidation : ValidationAttribute
    {
        public string Suggetion { get; set; }


        protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value,ValidationContext validationContext)
        {
            if (value != null)
            {
                if (value.ToString() == "123")
                {

                    return ValidationResult.Success;
                }
                else
                {


                    return new ValidationResult(Suggetion);

                }
            }else
                return new ValidationResult("Value is Null");

        }
    }
}
```

**View:**

```
 @Html.EditorFor(model => model.PartNumber)
 @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PartNumber)
```

[image]

Comment: After testing if part was alternate and setting the Validation property to the found alternate part I used: return new ValidationResult(AltPart);.  Then [PartAlternateValidation(AltPart = "Use Alternate Part: {0}")] for the add part model.  Thanks!